# I keep getting “Acces denied” notification when I use some cmd commands,although I'm in Administrator Mode

Tags: windows, command-line

I start recently to learn the command-prompt commands.I started with some basic commands:dir,cd,mkdir and move.I tried to move a directory from c:/users/user/documents/ called P1.I wanted to move the respective directory(P1)in d:(root directory).But I keep recevieng the "Acces denied" notification, although I'm using the cmd in Administrator mode. There're no relevant tutorials on youtube or topics discussing a solution for this.Can someone help me with that ? I don't what to use other scripts for solving my problem,I need a solution that will solve these problem on any windows machine(starting from 7) if it's needed. I also disabled UAC, but had no effect.
here's the actual command:"c:/Users/User/Documents>move P1 d:"

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Administrator Mode"?

If you right-click on a program, and select "Run As Administrator", that basically just runs the command with UAC-elevated permissions.  That has nothing to do with what account you use.

If you are using an account in the Administrators group, including Administrator, you may not have permissions for every file.  However, you can take ownership of a file that you aren't the owner of.  Then, as the owner, you will have permissions to give yourself permissions.

There may still be things you don't have permissions for.  For instance, you may read files from an optical drive.  However, Windows may say you don't have permission to write to a commercially manufactured CD-ROM disc.  This may be because the driver was designed to refuse permissions, because of the physical impossibility of the requested task.

Memory separation may also prohibit certain actions.  Such memory separation is now built into Windows to help with security.  (Windows 98 had much less support for memory separation.)

Note that in most software designed for Windows, backslashes () are typically used to separate directories.  Trying to use forward slashes (/) can work in some cases, and not others, so using \ may be safer.

If none of this answered your question, you may want to provide more details:

- What are the permissions on the file that you are trying to copy
- what are the permissions of the directory (a.k.a. "folder") where you are trying to copy the data to?
- What operating system are you using?